# Send Email For a selected file

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow

I am trying to send an email for a selected file in power automate, I would like to see the flow only on subfolders which I have set the flow but not on all Subfolders.

Ex: Parent Folder
SubFolder 1
SubFolder 2
SubFolder 3 - I want to see the flow only on this subfolder 3 and its subfolders, but not for complete library. And that is for only selected file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Reza Dorani's video, [Run Power Automate flow from SharePoint - For a selected item trigger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Hp9CTd8zQU).  The entire video is gold, but at minute mark 18:00 he details how to conditionally show/hide the run flow button based on another column's value.  I hope this is enough to get you started.  Good luck!